# How to set up Cygwin to use DOS file endings?

Tags: windows, cygwin, line-endings

I have following problem:

When I run a shell script, that has been stored with CR+LF line endings, I get following error:

```
myscript.sh: line 1: cd: $'somedir\\someotherdir\r': No such file or directory
```

I have researched the problem and there is a solution for Cygwin shell, found [here](http://ptolemy.eecs.berkeley.edu/ptolemyII/ptIIlatest/cygwin.htm):

1. Create a .bashrc file
2. Put this inside:

   ```
   export SHELLOPTS
   set -o igncr
   ```
3. Reload Cygwin shell

However, I use [Cmder](http://cmder.net/) and I'd like to apply this in it. But, I do not know how. As noted [here](http://ptolemy.eecs.berkeley.edu/ptolemyII/ptIIlatest/cygwin.htm), Cygwin used to have an option to set the use of DOS file endings as a default during installation, but got rid of it (no idea why).

The weirdest thing of all is that I have the same setup on my older computer, also Windows 10, and everything works well, even with CRLF endings...

Comment: wrong question. On cygwin use LF endings or something will always break down in some package.

Comment: Okay, but how do you explain that everything worked on the old computer?

Comment: How old was your cygwin installation ? The text/binary option was removed from setup in 2013.

Comment: Yeah, it's possible that it was older. I don't have the computer at hand atm. I however probably would stick with LF endings. Just was curious why it was working before and now doesn't (what was the reason to shut down the support).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem with upgrading from a *very* old Cygwin version to the latest.
For just a very few limited "sed" invocations, I explicitly added a \r to the output to keep some other downstream, non-cygwin tools happy.

```
sed s_(complicated-regex-with-capture)_\1\r_g infile > outfile
```

A regex guru could probably improve upon this approach to optionally capture and emit the "\r" only if it is found in the data.

```
sed s_(capture1)(capture\r-or-empty:\r*)$_\1\2_g infile > outfile
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use dos2unix which can be installed with Cygwin.